# Vigenere cipher difficulties

Tags: c, cs50, vigenere

This is a Vigenere cypher for cs50. It's my first time coding and I'm going around this for a week now, and I don't seem to be able to print first letter after the loop finishes for the first time.

For example:

```
jharvard@appliance (~/Dropbox): ./viginere abcde 
You're key is abcde
Type your text: 
aaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaa
abcde bcde bcdebc debcde
```

First `a` is printed but then it starts on `b` and in the end it doesn't print every letter. The key is chosen by the user.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

```
for (int i = 0, j = strlen(plain_text), l = 0; i < j; i++)
{    
    int rotation_1 = (tolower(plain_text[i]) + (key[l] - 97)) % 122;
    int rotation_2 = (plain_text[i] + (key[l] - 97)) % 122;

    //if it is a letter
    if (isalpha(plain_text[i]))
    {   
        l = l % strlen(key);
        //if the it is uppercase
        if (isupper(plain_text[i]))
        { 
            printf("%c", toupper(rotation_1)); 
        }
        //else if it is lowercase
        else
        {  
            printf("%c", rotation_2);   
        }
        l++;        
    }                     
    // if it is not a letter we print it as it is     
    else           
    {
        printf("%c", plain_text[i]);
    }            
}
```

Comment: Don't use `l` as a variable name, it looks confusingly similar to `1`.

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319393/vigenere-cipher-black-hawk-down

Comment: You should update `l` this way: `l = (l + 1) % strlen(key);` at the end of the `if` branch and remove the update code at the beginning.

Comment: The logic is faulty.  The way you compute `rotation_1` and `rotation_2` does not yield letters in the proper range. You should compute the letter index, adjust it using the key, take the modulo, and finally add the base letter (`'A'` for uppercase, `'a'` for lowercase).

Comment: OK I think I get it.. I won't use "l" anymore, but even tho I'm not computing words correctly for some examoles it works, ill to break rotation_1 to simples and easier parts and see if I can follow your advice

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simpler version with the logic fixed:

```
for (int i = 0, n = strlen(plain_text), k = 0, klen = strlen(key); i < n; i++) {
    int c = (unsigned char)plain_text[i];

    //if it is a letter
    if (isalpha(c)) {
        if (isupper(c)) {
            c = 'A' + (c - 'A' + key[k] - 'a') % 26;
        } else {
            c = 'a' + (c - 'a' + key[k] - 'a') % 26;
        }
        k = (k + 1) % klen;
    }
    putchar(c);
}
```

It is important to cast `plain_text[i]` as `(unsigned char)` because `isalpha` and `isupper` are only defined for all values of `unsigned char` and `EOF`.  `char` may be signed by default of your platform.

Also note that `putchar(c)` is much more efficient than `printf("%c", c);`

Comment: wow thank you, so many things I dont know yet, this is exactly what I needed, thanks.